# Is the Soul Geyser the most damaging spell in the game? or is there something more devastating?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I was looking up stuff on youtube and people whom demonstrate Soul Geyser spells always do 2000-3000 damage. This is the highest damage i've seen done by mages in dark souls 2. Is it actually the most damaging spell? or is there something with greater damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Climax is pretty devastating as well. It uses souls to power the spell, and can (generally) one shot almost anything. Including most other players.

Comment: Please note that this is a Hex, not a sorcery. The answer is still correct, since the OP asked for spell and not sorcery.